# O background da minha página desajusta com diferentes tamanho da janela do navegador

Tags: html, css, background

Boa tarde, estou fazendo uma página com HTML + CSS e estou com o seguinte problema:
Estou programando com a tela dividida entre o VSCODE e o navegador, e defini o background do body da seguinte maneira:

```
           background-image: url('url da minha imagem');
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-position: center;
           background-size: cover;
       }
```

Quando o navegador fica no modo da tela dividida, a página fica conforme eu quero, como mostrado na imagem.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Só que quando eu abro em tela cheia, fica desproporcional.
Teria algum jeito para eu configurar o site em tela cheia ou alguma outra forma para eu resolver esse problema?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente é usar o `background-position: top center`

Isso vai deixar o bg sempre centralizado na horizontal, mas na vertical o topo da imagem sempre fica no topo da página.

Veja a img abaixo, o box vermelho é a imagem de bg, e a borda azul os  limites do `viewport`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]